# trying to install Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, linux, jupyter

I am new to Linux and python. I am trying to install Jupyter notebook but getting the following error:

[image]
[image]

Please help me resolve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to error, you don`t have permissions,
so Use:

sudo pip install numpy

But here is way to install jupyter:

sudo apt-get -y install ipython ipython-notebook

sudo -H pip install jupyter

Than run the jupyter :

jupyter notebook

For further info refer:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-jupyter-notebook-to-run-ipython-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1):

Brother use sudo with this command
like:

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

and you mentioned that you are trying to install Jupiter NoteBook but this is for numpy.
And if you want to install Notebook got for this URL:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-jupyter-notebook-to-run-ipython-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: ya. thanks for the answer. actually i had uploaded the wrong image, but the error message was the same though for both jupyter and numpy. thanks again